# benefits for setting dependency interface in cmake target_link_libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I use CMake in my C++ project for a while, and my project is an application (not a library) consisting of multiple sub modules, where each module depends on other internal modules in the same project, and depends on multiple third party libraries as well, and each of them is built using CMake.

Currently, we use `PUBLIC` in `target_link_libraries` when specifying these dependencies. I read some articles/documentations [1][2][3] about this topic, and know the general difference between `PUBLIC`/`INTERFACE`/`PRIVATE`, and know that it is recommended to specify different visibility as detailed as possible. But since I am building an application but not a library, I am not worried that internal APIs are "leaked" accidentally, is there any other benefit that we should choose to use non `PUBLIC` visibility like `PRIVATE`? For example, besides affecting linking's speed, does it affect compilation speed? If linking doesn't take too much time, does it still make sense to optimize compilation speed by exploring this option? Does it affect the size of the binary in the end? Or is there any other benefit for controlling this behavior? Thanks.

[1] https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html
[2] https://leimao.github.io/blog/CMake-Public-Private-Interface/
[3] https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2016-May/063400.html

Comment: `target_link_libraries` has nothing to do with symbols visibility. `PUBLIC/INTERFACE/PRIVATE` is about CMake targets inheriting properties, it does not affect symbols.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks. Inheritance seems more about how it behaves, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html this documentation call them "keywords can be used to specify both the link dependencies and the link interface in one command". I am not sure what this term should be called exactly.

Comment: It could definetly affect compilation speed. You'll probably have include dirs associated with the libs using `target_include_directories` and the more include directories a target sees, the longer the compiler could take to identify the path of the file you're including. Probably the effect is neglectible, but it's there. In addition to this you'll also see all the possible headers in the autocompletion of your IDE making it more time consuming to identify the intended one... Note that there are other properties that are propagated with `PUBLIC` as well, e.g. `target_compile_definitions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### You should ***absolutely always*** use a visibility specifier with `target_link_libraries`.

Whether or not `target_link_libraries(target lib)` is considered to be `PRIVATE` or `PUBLIC` by default depends on whether or not you use visibility specifiers *elsewhere* in the CMakeLists.txt. This risk of changing the visibility of a library simply by adding a *different* library should really be all the justification anyone needs to just use the maintainer-recommended best practices.

Having too many public dependencies will eventually lead to pointlessly long link lines, which can indeed bloat link times as the linker will need to determine that a symbol is not relevant. Worse, it's possible that one library that didn't need to be public will *win* a symbol conflict incorrectly and cause trouble. There's simply no reason to intentionally set up an inaccurate dependency model.

Finally, for executables, which visibility specifier to use is usually simple to choose: 99% of the time, it will be `PRIVATE`. However, this is not *always* the case. If you are building a plugin system, say, you might have `ENABLE_EXPORTS` set on your executable. In this case, libraries may in fact link to the executable target and visibility becomes relevant again.